# How do I scale up and down an Elastic Beanstalk application via command line without set the desired instance number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, scale, ebcli

I am new on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I have deployed an application via eb cli. For me scale up or down my application via eb cli I have found the following command

```
eb scale number-of-instances
```

but in my scenario I would like to scape up or down only once instance per time.

What I am looking for is a way to scale it by using its cli with some command like

```
eb scale up/down
```

but this kind of command is not supported.

Is there a way in which I am able to scale my application this way via `eb` cli, or I must always set the number of instances that I want?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "only one instance per time".

Comment: Hello Mark, what I want is to be able to increment or decrement only one instance, assuming I do not know how many instances my application has

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by getting the instance number via

```
eb status - v
```

and than based on the value of Running instances I execute the command

```
eb scale number-of-instances
```

I know that this is not the best solution, but this is how I solved my issue